Multicollinearity in multiple LOGISTIC regression in R - error when calculating VIFs
I'm attempting to check for multicollinearity in a multiple logistic regression model, where the outcome is coded as 0/1 but predictor variables are factor (categorical) like sex, age groups ("18 to 39", "40-64", etc), race/ethnicity, and diabetes ("yes"/"no").
Data frame looks like this:



id
age
sex
race_eth
diabetes




001
<18
male
black
yes



Steps I've taken:

Make the model using glm function, specifying family=binomial and link="logit"

This results in

warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred"


Use vif() to calculate VIFs for each variable. This results in "Error: there are aliased coefficients in the model"

From what I read online, using the vif() function is appropriate for character variables, even multi-level variables like my dataset has.
Online resources suggest looking at correlation matrices via cor() functions but this only applies to numeric variables.
What am I doing wrong? What can I do to resolve the error and calculate VIFs?

Does the summary of the glm output give NA values for any of the coefficients?

You apparently have sets of perfectly multicollinear variables among your predictors (in which case the VIF would be infinite anyway ...)
Can't tell exactly what's going on without seeing more information about your data, but one way it can happen is if you specify an interaction (e.g. age*sex*race_eth) where some of the combinations don't occur (e.g. there are no Hispanic females with age >70). You could check this via e.g. with(<your_data>, table(age, sex, race_eth)).
To diagnose the multicollinearity more specifically you can do, for example:
X <- model.matrix(<your model formula>, data = <your_data>)
caret::findLinearCombos(X)

(you can also look at cor(X), since X is numeric (the categorical predictors get expanded into contrasts/dummy variables), but checking pairwise collinearity is often not good enough to detect multicollinearity ...)

Thank you! This is my code, I don't have any interaction:

model<- glm(outcome~ Site + Age_new + Sex + race_ethnicity+ WHO_region+ country + language + hiv+ diabetes+ contact+ homeless + insurance, family = binomial (link = logit), data=dataframe)

I expected to have some multicollinearity, e.g. country and language, for instance. I do have some small cell sizes (e.g. there's no one with HIV). Could that cause it?

@flailing-in-r What would you accomplish by including a variable in your model when there's no variation on that variable in your sample?

@BryanKrause Good point! I can remove the HIV variable for instance, but there are levels in other variables that are 0 (e.g. no American Indian for "race_ethnicity" even though all other levels in that variable, like Asian, have data). Should I reformat the variable to remove the levels that have 0?

@flailing-in-r Same thing, really: how are you going to estimate a coefficient for American Indian when no one in your sample fits that description? (Yes; see "drop levels")

Missing factor levels in a variable don't seem to be enough to trigger a problem, e.g. set.seed(101); dd <- data.frame(y=rbinom(100, prob = 0.5, size =1), f = factor(rep(1:2, each = 50), levels = 1:3)); glm(y~f, family = binomial, data = dd) just drops the missing level from the model. If you have a factor with only one level present you should get an error "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels". At this point we're guessing, we need a reproducible example before we can get any further ...

Alternatively, please run the code that I suggested (cor/findLinearCombos) and see if that answers your question. If it doesn't, please edit your question to include the results of those tests

Just to update - the cor/findLinearCombos did work. I also created dummy variables and used a correlation matrix. Both approaches led to me a potentially problematic variable. Dropping that variable allowed VIFs to be generated and the model to run.

If this solved your problem you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.
